# nodejs - output array of images

Tags: node.js

I have the following request handler...

```
function images(res) {

    fs.readdir("./img", function(err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var results = [];

        files.forEach(function(file) {
            var dot = file.lastIndexOf(".") + 1,
                ext = file.substr(dot, file.length),
                fmt = ["jpg", "png", "gif"];

            if (fmt.indexOf(ext) > -1)
                   results.push(file);
            }
        });

        showImages(results);
    });

    function showImages(images) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            res.write("<img src='http://127.0.0.1:8888/img/" + images[i] + "' />");
        }
        res.end();
    }
}
```

Which, when called, outputs the following HTML...

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src='http://127.0.0.1:8888/img/image01.jpg' />
        <img src='http://127.0.0.1:8888/img/image02.png' />
        <img src='http://127.0.0.1:8888/img/image03.png' />
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason the images aren't being displayed. Any ideas as to why?

Thanks.

Comment: file permissions allow read for the user the server is running as? correct port for the server?

Comment: Do you have a static file server serving the img directory?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have a static file server running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using express, you need to move your files from `./img` to `./public/img`. Otherwise you need to set-up static files.

Comment: Thanks Gabi, I have set up node-static