# How to go about creating a gallery of images from an array of urls in node.

Tags: css, node.js, ejs, node-modules

I have an array of images which I'd like to display an array of images and also be able to select multiple images etc.

Thanks, I couldn't find any resources online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs - output array of images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798295/nodejs-output-array-of-images)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your solution on google https://www.google.it/#q=image+gallery+node.js